# Google Sheets - Run script based on value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm very new to scripting and really need some help getting started.

Basically I'm trying to develop a simple script to show a warning message when a certain value in a cell has been selected from a drop down list.

When the option 'Behind' has been selected I just want a simple popup window or something to say 'Review is needed'.

I've explored 'toast' but I'm not sure how I'd get the script to run based on the value.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm going bald :(

Emma

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of what you have already ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this kind of behavior without writing your own script. See [Data validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

1. Select the cells for which you want this to apply
2. Click on `Data -> Data Validation` in the menu
3. Set your criteria for allowed values
4. On invalid data, select either `Show Warning` or `Reject Input` (the latter will reject the input and show a toast)
5. Put a checkbox in `Show validation help text` to add a custom warning text